# Show error only in empty fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(function($){

    var fields = $('.registerForm');

    fields.blur(function(){ 

        var field = $(this);
        var text = field.context.id;

        if(field.val().length == 0 || field.val() == 0){
            $('#' + text).addClass('error')
        }
        if(email.val().length && email_match.val().length > 0) {
            if(email.val() !== email_match.val() || field.val().length == 0){
                $('#email, #email_match').addClass('error')
            } else {
                $('#email, #email_match').removeClass('error')
            }
        }
    });
    fields.focus(function(){
        var field = $(this);
        var text = field.context.id;
        if(field){
            $('#' + text).removeClass('error')
        }
    });
});
```

This peace of code adds the class error only to empty inputs or if the email and pass not equals.
Now i want to do the same only when pressing submit it must give the class only to empty spaced.

```
$('#registerForm').on('submit', function(e){
if(fields.val().length == 0 || fields.var() == 0) 
 //Give only the empty area's the class error
e.preventDefault();
});
```

How do i do this ?

The form id is `registerForm` and all inputs has the class `registerForm`

Comment: You should try [jQuery Validator](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Comment: You could simplify the `if` statement to `if ($(this).val())` . Any empty string is a falsey value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('#registerForm').on('submit', function(e){

   //Give only the empty area's the class error
   e.preventDefault();
   fields.each(function() {
       if ($(this).val().length == 0 || $(this).var() == 0) {
           $(this).addClass('error');
       }
   });

});
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. I had the idea it was something in that direction but didn't know about the each() function.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly It can help you. I did not check result but it might help you.

```
jQuery(function($){

    var issuccess=true;
    var fields = $('.registerForm');
    $('#registerForm').on('submit', function(e){
    if(fields.val().length == 0 || fields.var() == 0)
       issuccess=false; 
    if(email.val().length && email_match.val().length > 0) {
            if(email.val() !== email_match.val() || field.val().length == 0){
                  issuccess=false;
            } else {

            }
        }

if(issuccess)
  return true;
else
return false;


    });

});
```